# i dont know how to create a dynamic module aws_sagemaker_user_profile for each user in sagemaker to

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-sagemaker

I don't know how to create a dynamic resource module

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_user_profile" "user_profile" {
  domain_id = aws_sagemaker_domain.sagemaker_domain.id
  user_profile_name = var.user_profile_name
}
```

for every sagemaker user. The idea would be that this block would be displayed for each username entered in the tfvars file with the user_profile_name variable.

Comment: Well, for one, this isn't valid terraform code. Also, it would be beneficial to see how you have defined the `user_proflie_name` variable.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question, you want to create a Sagemaker user profile for every value defined under the `user_profile_name` variable. To achieve that, you would first need to define the variable like this:

```
variable "user_profile_name" {
  type    = set
  default = ["user1", "user2"] # you can add as many as you like
}
```

Since you want to create a profile for each of the values, you can use the [`for_each` meta-argumen](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each)t. The final code would then look like:

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_user_profile" "user_profile" {
  for_each          = var.user_profile_name
  domain_id         = aws_sagemaker_domain.sagemaker_domain.id
  user_profile_name = each.key
}
```

Since the variable is defined as a set, the `each.key` and `each.value` give the [same result](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#the-each-object).

> `each.value` — The map value corresponding to this instance. (**If a set was provided, this is the same as each.key.**)